# converting full alphabet to numbers in OBJ-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to convert the alphabet to a string of number or integers. I can do it this way but I want to know if there is a better way of doing it? I have to convert 4 letters to the corrosponding number so I have created a NSMutableArray with the alphabet and then done this it is reading a string then pulling the string apart one piece at a time.

EDIT: So if my msg was "MNOP" i want a string that is "13141516"

```
 alphabetArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[alphabetArray insertObject:@"0" atIndex:0];
[alphabetArray insertObject:@"A" atIndex:1];
[alphabetArray insertObject:@"B" atIndex:2];
[alphabetArray insertObject:@"C" atIndex:3];
[alphabetArray insertObject:@"D" atIndex:4];
[alphabetArray insertObject:@"E" atIndex:5];
[alphabetArray insertObject:@"F" atIndex:6];
[alphabetArray insertObject:@"G" atIndex:7];
[alphabetArray insertObject:@"H" atIndex:8];
[alphabetArray insertObject:@"I" atIndex:9];
[alphabetArray insertObject:@"J" atIndex:10];
[alphabetArray insertObject:@"K" atIndex:11];
[alphabetArray insertObject:@"L" atIndex:12];
[alphabetArray insertObject:@"M" atIndex:13];
[alphabetArray insertObject:@"N" atIndex:14];
[alphabetArray insertObject:@"O" atIndex:15];
[alphabetArray insertObject:@"P" atIndex:16];
[alphabetArray insertObject:@"Q" atIndex:17];
[alphabetArray insertObject:@"R" atIndex:18];
[alphabetArray insertObject:@"S" atIndex:19];
[alphabetArray insertObject:@"T" atIndex:20];
[alphabetArray insertObject:@"U" atIndex:21];
[alphabetArray insertObject:@"V" atIndex:22];
[alphabetArray insertObject:@"W" atIndex:23];
[alphabetArray insertObject:@"X" atIndex:24];
[alphabetArray insertObject:@"Y" atIndex:25];
[alphabetArray insertObject:@"Z" atIndex:26];

NSRange range1 = NSMakeRange(0, 1);
NSRange range2 = NSMakeRange(1, 1);
NSRange range3 = NSMakeRange(2, 1);
NSRange range4 = NSMakeRange(3, 1);


NSString *letter1 = [msg substringWithRange:range1];  
NSString *letter2 = [msg substringWithRange:range2];
NSString *letter3 = [msg substringWithRange:range3]; 
NSString *letter4 = [msg substringWithRange:range4];

NSString *msgAsInt = [[NSString alloc]
             initWithFormat:@"%d%d%d%d",
             [alphabetArray  indexOfObject:letter1 ],
             [alphabetArray  indexOfObject:letter2 ],
             [alphabetArray  indexOfObject:letter3 ],
             [alphabetArray  indexOfObject:letter4 ]];
```

Any advice would be great. I havent tested this yet but it looks ok

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: What is the purpose of this line? 
[alphabetArray insertObject:@"0" atIndex:0];?

Answer (score 3):

If you simply want 'message as int', do like this (assuming UTF-8):

```
NSMutableString *msgAsInt = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < msg.length; i++)
    [msgAsInt appendFormat:@"%02d", [msgAsInt characterAtIndex:i] - 'A'];
```

Also, you'd better add that `02` before `%d` if you want to recover  the message later.

Comment: That's exactly what I was typing! Note that this requires that all the characters in the string are between 'A' and 'Z' or weird things will happen.

Comment: Yes, but the answer implies it anyway.

Comment: So if the message was "MNOP" that would give me "12131415" ? I am sending messages to the phone and am trying to cut down on the length so I decided to use letters instead of numbers. I might not have described what I was trying to do well

Comment: Methinks you're approaching the problem wrong.  If you want to save on length, use smaller datatypes and/or compression, not some wacky number-to-letter conversion.  Depending on their size, numbers can be stored in datatypes much smaller than an integer.

Comment: So what should I write instead?

Answer (score 1):

If performance is important (e.g. you have thousands of strings to convert), you may use buffered read and write:

```
NSString *string = @"MNOP";

NSUInteger bufferSize = 4;
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, MIN(bufferSize,[string length]));

unichar inBuffer[bufferSize];
unichar outBuffer[bufferSize * 2];

[string getCharacters:inBuffer range:range];
NSUInteger outLength = 0;

for ( NSUInteger i = 0; i < range.length; i++)
{
    unichar character = inBuffer[i];
    if ( character >= 'A' && character <= 'Z' ) {
        int value = character - 'A' + 1;
        outBuffer[outLength++] = (value / 10) + '0';
        outBuffer[outLength++] = (value % 10) + '0';
    }
    else {
        // error management
    }
}

NSString *result = [NSString stringWithCharacters:outBuffer length:outLength];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're only dealing with uppercase letters from A to Z, you can rely on the UTF8 values of the characters. Do something like:

```
NSMutableString *msgAsInt = [NSMutableString string];
char *cMsg = calloc(5);
if ([msg getCString:cMsg maxLength:4 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        [msgAsInt appendFormat:@"%d", (cMsg[i] - ('A' - 1))];
    }
}
else {
    // there was a problem...
}
```